# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS laptop boots to tty1 screen

Tags: 22.04, desktop-environments, tty

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in my Dell Vostro 5568, it was booting normally but later on, after an update, it always boots to the **tty1 screen** and I have to enter the username and password multiple times which is annoying.

**HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS PROBLEM**
also, tell me the shortcut key *(if any)* to access the *GUI* back.

Here is the picture for instance [ubuntu 22.04 tty1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlUkT.png)

Comment: You can switch between the TTYs by `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`-`F7`. If there is a running desktop environment it mus be at TTY1 (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`) or TTY2 by default.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Do you see a text console with a normal login prompt or maybe an error message, e.g. about file system inconsistencies? Show what exactly you get.